# Prove that $f=cz^n$ using connectedness argument.

Tags: complex-analysis

Could you help me with the following?

> Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(0)=0$, and for every $M>0$  the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C}:-M<f(z)<M\}$ is connected. Prove that $f(z)=cz^n$ for some $c\in \mathbb{C}$ and some integer n.

I tried to show that the function $g(z)=f(z)/z^n$ where $n$ is the order of zero of $f$, is bounded and to use Liouville. But I can't see any way to involve the second assumption. Probably it needs the Schwarz reflection principle or someone else told me that maybe  Picard's theorem could help.

Comment: What does $-M<f(z)<M$ mean for complex numbers ?

Comment: It is the preimage of the interval $[-M,M]$

Comment: Please share your thought so far :)

Comment: Can $|f|$ ever have a local maximum?

Comment: I dont know about $|f|$ but $\Re f$ cannot.

Comment: I tried to show that the function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ where $n$  is the order of zero of f is bounded and to use Liouville. But i can't see any way to involve the second assumption. Probably it needs the Schwarz reflection principle or someone else told me that maybe the Picard's theorem could help.

Answer (score 1):

For small $M>0$, this set contains points near $z=0$, but is disjoint from a suitable small annulus $r_1<|z|<r_2$ (because $f(z)\approx az^k$ near zero). Thus $z=0$ is the only zero. For the same reason, the singularity at $z=\infty$ cannot be essential. Thus $f$ is a polynomial with $z=0$ as its only zero.